# Referring to the triggering object in the done() block of a post() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `post()` call bound to the `click()` method of a group of images.

Inside the `post()` call I can refer to `jQuery(this)` and with that get access to the originating object. (e.g. data parameters, or change its status):

```
jQuery('.vote .magic_button').click(function() {
  jQuery.post(url, {
      action: 'ajax_vote',
      'vote_target': jQuery(this).data('postid')
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // $img = jQuery(this).find('img');         
    })
});
```

When the AJAX call returns, after verifying the response, I want to refer to the image that was originally clicked, but that is no longer `this` in this new context.

How can I access this without having to pass the info back inside the `data` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `var that = this` workaround or just use ES5 .bind function to set the `this` correctly!

```
jQuery('.vote .magic_button').click(function() {
  jQuery.post(url, {
      action: 'ajax_vote',
      'vote_target': jQuery(this).data('postid')
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // $img = jQuery(this).find('img');         
    }.bind(this))
});
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: This seems a bit more elegant than the "self" assignment trick. But does `bind` has an additional requirement? Does it work on regular JS, or do I need a pre-processor?

Comment: Nope nothing, just a relatively up to date browser. See compatibility table in the linked documentation.

Comment: Mmmmh.... In FF Dev I get a very nice `jQuery.post(...).done(...).bind is not a function`...

Comment: @artgb No, it sets the `this` value when used within that function.

Comment: @artgb Sorry I had a typo. The `bind` call is supposed to be attached to the `done` function. FIXED
Also see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v20j8jet/2/